# Number of tasktrackers for given number of Mapper

Tags: mapreduce

If 100 Mappers are running in Hadoop 1.x, How many task-trackers will get initiated to complete the Mapper job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having mentioned only the mappers, I guess it is a map only job.

First of all, task trackers are hadoop daemons that would be up and running in "all" compute nodes of the cluster. So The real question has to be about the number of map slots which would be utilized to finish the job.

In a (single node) pseudo distributed cluster with 2 map slots, both the slots will be utilized at least  50 times to execute 100 map tasks, considering zero speculative task executions during the course of the job (and map tasks of no other jobs are running simultaneously).

In a cluster with at least 100 compute nodes, with one map slot free in each task tracker, then these 100 slots will be used to complete the job (with no speculative executions).